# Annualised return on investment in percent for X as Investor (simple interest)

Tags: microsoft-excel

It will help to have a field that will show annualized return on investment for lender (investor) as I borrow and repay to the lender.

[image]

I am advised to use XLRR function, which I did:

[image]

Getting #VALUE! error.

It is instructed in the Excel manual: If any number in dates is not a valid date, XIRR returns the #VALUE! error value.

I have checked data type of dates and it is date type.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation of an internal interest rate (IRR) is based of the entire sequence of cash flows during the considered period. T**here must be a positive and a negative number in the sequence**.
In your case, you can only compute IRR after 24/08/2022 to be mathematically computable, **but it does not make sense from a financial point of view**.

Try with a simpler cash flow sequence of a 10% yield 3 years bond of USD100 value:

```
2023 -100 (you buy the bond)
2024 +10 (1 year coupon)
2025 +10 (2nd year coupon)
2026 +110 (last year coupon + principal repayment)
```

If you compute the IRR for the complete 2023-2026 sequence you'll find 10% as expected.

But if you compute it on the 2023-2025 you'll obtain -63%! (it is a valid number only in case of complete default)

And if you try to compute on 2023 only you'll get an error.

Comment: It helped. Is there any other function that could help me what I actually need?

Comment: IRR is well adapted to complex cash flows, but you need to have the complete sequence (or a given time horizon eg IRR over 40 years for infrastructure). Otherwise, given your cash flows are not regular, you'll need to keep track for a given period of both capital and interest, and then compute the return for this given period, ie interest/capital adjusted for period duration (there maybe an excel for that)